# paperjs draw 0 to 360º arc using mouse events

Tags: javascript, svg, drawing, paperjs

I´m trying to draw an arc using mouse events with paper.js

The user must be able to draw an arc from 0 degree to 360 degree.
The issue that I´m facing is that I can draw 270 degree arc but more than 270, the arc flips to another quadrant.

Start point must be located anywhere

A sketch can be found here:

http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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

and this is the implemented code:

```
var arc_cse;

var radius=200;
var center=new Point(400,400);
var start=new Point(400,500);


var c1 = new Path.Circle({
    center: center,
    radius: 2,
    fillColor: 'black'
}); 

arc_cse = new Path({
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        strokeCap: 'round',  
    });    

           
tool.onMouseMove = function(event) {

    var p=new Point(event.point.x,event.point.y);
    var v1=start-center;
    var v2=p-center;
    var angle=(v2.angleInRadians-v1.angleInRadians);
    
    var arcval=arc_CRD(v1.angleInRadians,v2.angleInRadians,angle,center,radius);
    
    arc_cse.remove();
    arc_cse= new Path.Arc(arcval);
}

function arc_CRD(alpha1,alpha2,angle,center,radius){
   
    return {
        from: {
            x: center.x + radius*Math.cos(alpha1),
            y: center.y + radius*Math.sin(alpha1)
        },
        through: {
            x: center.x + radius * Math.cos(alpha1 + (alpha2-alpha1)/2),
            y: center.y + radius * Math.sin(alpha1 + (alpha2-alpha1)/2)
        },
        to: {
            x: center.x + radius*Math.cos(alpha1+(alpha2-alpha1)),
            y: center.y + radius*Math.sin(alpha1+(alpha2-alpha1))
        },
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        strokeCap: 'round'
    }
   
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly tons of ways to do this but here's how I would do it: [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).
This should help you finding the proper solution to your own use case.

```js
function dot(point, color) {
    const item = new Path.Circle({ center: point, radius: 5, fillColor: color });
    item.removeOnMove();
}

function drawArc(from, center, mousePoint) {
    const radius = (from - center).length;
    const circle = new Path.Circle(center, radius);
    const to = circle.getNearestPoint(mousePoint);
    const middle = (from + to) / 2;

    const throughVector = (middle - center).normalize(radius);
    const angle = (from - center).getDirectedAngle(to - center);
    const through = angle <= 0
        ? center + throughVector
        : center - throughVector;

    const arc = new Path.Arc({
        from,
        through,
        to,
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 2
    });

    circle.removeOnMove();
    arc.removeOnMove();

    // Visual helpers
    dot(from, 'orange');
    dot(center, 'black');
    dot(mousePoint, 'red');
    dot(to, 'blue');
    dot(middle, 'lime');
    dot(through, 'purple');
    circle.strokeColor = 'black';

    return arc;
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    drawArc(view.center + 100, view.center, event.point);
}
```

---

### Edit

In answer to your comment, here is a more mathematical approach: [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).
This is based on your code and has exactly the same behavior so you should have no difficulty using it.
The key of both implementation is the `Point.getDirectedAngle()` method which allow you to adapt the behavior depending on the through point side.

```js
const center = new Point(400, 400);
const start = new Point(400, 500);

const c1 = new Path.Circle({
    center: center,
    radius: 2,
    fillColor: 'black'
});

let arc;

function getArcPoint(from, center, angle) {
    return center + (from - center).rotate(angle);
}

function drawArc(from, center, mousePoint) {
    const directedAngle = (from - center).getDirectedAngle(mousePoint - center);
    const counterClockwiseAngle = directedAngle < 0
        ? directedAngle
        : directedAngle - 360;

    const through = getArcPoint(from, center, counterClockwiseAngle / 2);
    const to = getArcPoint(from, center, counterClockwiseAngle);

    return new Path.Arc({
        from,
        through,
        to,
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        strokeCap: 'round'
    });
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    if (arc) {
        arc.remove();
    }
    arc = drawArc(start, center, event.point);
}
```

Comment: Thanks sasensi for you quick respone. Your approach is very clear and removes all the math I wrote. But I need some extra help. When the arc is drawn it has to have the same behaivour, drawing the same shape without flipping clockwise or counterclockwise. I tried use cross product to determine the direction but I haven´t found a nice solution yet.This happens with more than 180º arcs

Comment: I thought that you would be able to adapt it to your use case. I edited my answer to better help you.

Comment: Thanks Sasensi, but I think I didn´t explaint it right. With the current code you only can draw an arc counterclockwise 360º from starting point, but if you want to draw a 360º arc clockwise without changing the code,it starts with a full 360 arc. What I´m trying to do is draw the arc with the same shape clockwise and counterclockwise as the same manner as a 2D CAD app does. I tried to do so using vector cross product to determine when the user starts drawing clockwise or counterclosewise the drawing direction, but it doesn´t work so far

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with the 2D CAD behavior that you are mentioning but it is certainly doable. Maybe a couple of drawings would help explaining your goal and maybe this would be better to post this as a new question too as this one is starting to get messy.